# How can I better test equality for decorated objects?

Tags: ruby, rspec, draper

I'm having trouble with equality matchers in RSpec and Draper decorated objects.

**Specs to show what's going on:**

```
context 'how to use the right equality matcher' do
  let(:page) { build(:page) }
  let(:decorated_page) { page.decorate }

  it "should pass, but doesn't" do
    expect(decorated_page).to_not eq page
  end

  it 'proves the classes are different' do
    expect(decorated_page).to be_a PageDecorator
    expect(page).to be_a Page
    expect(decorated_page.class).to_not eq page.class
  end

  it 'has a work around' do
    expect(decorated_page).to be_decorated_with PageDecorator
    expect(page).to_not be_decorated_with PageDecorator
  end
end
```

I know RSpec has a [few different equality checkers](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/frames#Equivalence), and that `eq` is the "weakest" but I would have thought not having the same class would be a deal breaker.

As you can see, I have a work around for this case thanks to [Draper's matchers](https://github.com/drapergem/draper#rspec). But I feel like I must be missing something for that test to fail.

**Question:**

What equality matcher should I use to get the `should pass, but doesn't` test to pass?

Comment: The `eq` matcher just uses the `==` operator on the objects, so this isn't really an RSpec issue but a Draper issue.

Comment: what if you create page instead of build?

Comment: @DavidGrayson I agree. I hoped there was another equality matcher that would work for this case, but I think not. That's probably why Draper provides the work around matchers.

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov Nope, same problem. I think David has the right idea - this just isn't how Draper is expected to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're encountering two misunderstandings.

1. You're asking about testing whether the page is decorated or not. You shouldn't test for this. Instead, you should test for the outcome of the decoration, i.e. the behavior. For example if the decorator is supposed to add a new method "foo" then test that the "foo" method works the way you want.
2. The Draper decorator makes `model.decorate == model`. This intentionally makes the decoration "invisible" to testing code. For example, `expect(decorated_page).to eq page` will succeed, because RSpec is using `==` for the comparison, then Draper is intercepting `==`. This is why your spec that says "should pass, but doesn't" is behaving the way it is.

If you really do want to test that decoration happened to the page, try this:

```
expect(decorated_page.object).to eq page
```

If you really do want to test that the decorated page is different than the page, try this:

```
expect(decorated_page.object_id).to_not eq page.object_id
```

Comment: 1. the code for that test is `expect(decorated_page).to_not eq page` - as in, I think `decorated_page` should not equal `page`. That test fails - as in, RSpec things `decorated_page` and `page` are equal.
2. I have separate decorator tests to make sure the methods on the decorator work as expected. This test is to make sure the decoration is applied in the first place.

Comment: I like your idea for `expect(decorated_page.object).to eq page` - it tests that decoration happened, and that it happened on the right object. Thanks!

Comment: I added more info to explain better - see if that helps and let me know if you want more detail